# Set up a homebrew tap with a git repository on a private network

Tags: macos, git, github, osx-mavericks, homebrew

We're looking at ways to create custom packages and do package management for Macs on which the users do not have admin access. The packages are going to be tools and configurations that are for use within our company only and can not be placed on Github. Is there a way to set up a tap to a Git repository on our private network?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Homebrew now supports taps from everywhere. The only thing you need is an URL with a protocol `git` can understand.

Choose an username and a tap name, and ask your users to run the following command:

```
brew tap username/tapname https://the-url-to-your-repo.example.com
```

The `username/tapname` part will be used to refer to your tap in case there’s a conflict, between e.g. `vim` (the core formula) and `username/tapname/vim` (your own fork). You might want to use something like `yourcompany/packages`. The URL doesn’t need to be in `https`, you can use `git://` or anything else `git` understands.

Comment: This works great! It seems though, that the `url` in the Formula must still point to a public release (tarball). Have you found a way around this, so that the tarball can be protected in some way, perhaps by forcing the user to authenticate, or by some other means?

Comment: @wintron A bit late, but because `brew tap` uses `git clone`, it supports the same auth mechanisms. For example, it asks you for a username/password if you try to tap a private GitHub/Gitlab repo.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **brew any-tap** (https://github.com/telemachus/homebrew-anytap)

> brew any-tap is an external command that extends brew's built-in tap command. brew tap is a convenient way to add personal or non-standard repositories of formulas to Homebrew, but it only works on public GitHub repositories that follow specific naming conventions. By contrast, brew any-tap works with any git repository, public and private, on GitHub or anywhere else.

Comment: that one's been merged into `brew tap` by now.

Answer (score -1):

The `brew tap` command only supports taps hosted on the public GitHub.  But you can just clone your internal tap directly to `/usr/local/Library/Taps/yourcompany/homebrew-yoursoftware/` and run `brew tap --repair` to put the symlinks in place.  After that, it's indistinguishable from a regular tap.